# What value of `Name` and `Command` do you use in keyboard shortcut to allow copy / paste to / from clipboard

Tags: shortcut-keys, clipboard

I have the keyboard shortcuts screen open.  I'd like to add a Custom Shortcut which maps copy and paste to `Super + C` or `Super + V`.  However I don't know what to call this shortcuts name and command.  Is there a list of these anywhere?

Comment: @pa4080 perfect, thank you so much :)

Comment: I'm happy to help, @AJP!